# Equalizer like histogram in highcharts

Tags: charts, highcharts

How can I make equalizer like histogram in highcharts as shown in this figure- [image]

There is a similar solution to this here- https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=38013 but it doesn't completely fits in my case.

In the solution, If I'm trying to create histogram by providing these options but then stacks are getting vanished.

```
column: {
    pointPadding: 0,
    borderWidth: 0,
    groupPadding: 0,
    shadow: false,
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your chart is closer to heatmap. You can use `colsize` and `rowsize` properties and null points to show the grey part of the columns.

```
    series: [{
        type: 'heatmap',
        colsize: 0.9,
        rowsize: 0.7,
        data: [
            [0, 0, 10],
            [0, 1, 19],
            [0, 2, null],
            [0, 3, null],
            ...
        ]
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dxw3jne2/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.colsize

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.rowsize